# sharing common between two inherited Razor views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'd like to inherit Razor WebViewPage because there's some common code I want executed for every view, and some in specific model driven views.

I have 2 inherit classes

```
public abstract class TemplateEngine : WebViewPage  {
 ///...code
}
```

And

```
public abstract class TemplateEngine<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel> {
    ///...code
}
```

There's some code that I want to use regardless of the type of view - whether strongly typed or not, and some specific to the strongly typed view. I don't want to duplicate it - in essence I want the strongly-typed inherited view to have access to all the code I've written in the generic inherited view.

I'm wondering if I'm missing some basic concept... so any pointer would be great.

Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it.  My untyped class inherits from my typed clas with type dynamic.  I don't define anything new in the untyped class since it inherits everything I want.  Not sure that it's the best

```
abstract public class CxWebView<T> : WebViewPage<T>
{
    /* all of the methods & properties I want available in every view */
}

abstract public class CxWebView : CxWebView<dynamic>
{
}
```

in my views/web.config I set the base type to CxWebView

```
<pages pageBaseType="CxLib.Web.CxWebView">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Data" />
    <add namespace="System.Data.Entity" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Comment: It's kind of reverse of what I'd ideally want... where my typed class inherits from the untyped. The issue is that my typed class has lot of special view specific code only some pages use.